# Using Linq query to find in JObject array property put outside in same jobject

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of `JObject` and each `JObject` contains a property call `"roles"` i.e type of `JArray`.

So I'm trying to iterate `JArray` value and matched one role object  i have to put into outer JObject(Test,Test2) and finally return list of `JObject`.

**Input List of Jobject:**

```json
[
   {
      "SchemaName":"Test",
      "roles":[
         {
            "role":"create",
            "permission":{
               "create":true
            }
         },
         {
            "role":"read",
            "permission":{
               "read":true
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "SchemaName":"Test2",
      "roles":[
         {
            "role":"update",
            "permission":{
               "create":true
            }
         },
         {
            "role":"read",
            "permission":{
               "read":true
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In this list i have to match record with variable called `roleName` value as `"read"`. so all Jobject(Test,Test2) which contains in there `'roles'` JArray JObject role property value as `'read'`, construct new structure `JObject` and return list of `JObject`.

so far i tried linq query but still not got success.Here is the code

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = "[{\"SchemaName\":\"Test\",\"roles\":[{\"role\":\"create\",\"permission\":{\"create\":true}},{\"role\":\"read\",\"permission\":{\"read\":true}}]},{\"SchemaName\":\"Test2\",\"roles\":[{\"role\":\"update\",\"permission\":{\"update\":true}},{\"role\":\"read\",\"permission\":{\"read\":false}}]}]";
        
        JArray schemaArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
        string roleName="read";
        var matchedSchemasObjectForRole = (from schemaObject in schemaArray 
                                                         where 
                                                         schemaObject["roles"] != null 
                                                         && JArray.Parse(schemaObject["roles"].ToString()).Count > 0 
                                                         && JArray.Parse(schemaObject["roles"].ToString()).Any(x => x != null && x["role"].ToString() == roleName.ToString()?(schemaObject["role"]=roleName;schemaObject["permissions"]=x["permissions"]):x)
                                                         select schemaObject).ToList();
        
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matchedSchemasObjectForRole));
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```json
[
   {
      "SchemaName":"Test",
      "role":"read",
      "permission":{
         "read":true
      }
   },
   {
      "SchemaName":"Test2",
      "role":"read",
      "permission":{
         "read":false
      }
   }
]
```

How to get expected result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `Test2`'s `permisson.read` is `false`? If so, how do you calculate that value?

Comment: BTW your provided sample fails at the second line `JArray.Parse`. Your `jsonString` has an object on the top level rather than a collection/array.

Comment: @PeterCsala updated in question..by mistake missed array start bracket

Comment: @PeterCsala yes i m sure..it's doesn't matter what value is there...from array matched record(role property and input variable roleName) need to create in outside object like expected result.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? If so could you please mark the chosen solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output like this:

```
List<Schema> reducedSchemas = new List<Schema>();

const string RolesArrayName = "roles", RoleNodeName = "role", SchemaNodeName = "SchemaName";
string roleFilter = "read"; //Let's pretend that this value is received from user

var schemaArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (JObject schema in schemaArray)
{
    if (!schema.ContainsKey(RolesArrayName)) continue;
    var roles = (JArray)schema[RolesArrayName];
    foreach (JObject role in roles)
    {
        if (!role.TryGetValue(RoleNodeName, out var roleNameToken)) continue;

        var roleName = (string)roleNameToken;
        if (!string.Equals(roleName, roleFilter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;

        reducedSchemas.Add(new Schema {
            Name = (string)schema[SchemaNodeName],
            Role = roleName,
            Permission = new Permission() });
    }
}
```

- After the `JArray.Parse` call we can iterate through the semi-parsed array

  - Please note that if you would write `foreach (var schema in schemaArray)` then `schema`'s type would be `JToken`, but because we need `JObject` we should explicitly say that
- We use the `ContainsKey` to make sure that the given node is present

  - Even though we could use `TryGetValue` here as well it feels a bit clumsy since the `TryGetValue`'s out is a `JToken` which needs to be converted to `JArray`
- Whenever we have the `roles` we can iterate through them with the same trick what we did with `schemaArray`
- We try to get the `role` value if that node exists with `TryGetValue`
- After we have extracted the value we can compare the read value with the user given value
- If they are matching then we simply add a new `Schema` object to the `reducedSchemas` collection

The `Schema` can be defined like this

```
class Schema
{
    [JsonProperty("SchemaName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("permission")]
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

class Permission
{
    [JsonProperty("read")]
    public bool CanRead { get; set; }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Revised code according to comments

I've changed the `Permission` class definition to this:

```
class Permission
{
    [JsonProperty("granted")]
    public bool HasGranted { get; set; }
}
```

This indicates whether or not the access has been granted.
*Feel free to rename it to whatever suites you.*

The revised parsing logic looks like this:

```
var reduced = new List<Schema>();

const string RolesArrayName = "roles", RoleNodeName = "role",
    SchemaNodeName = "SchemaName", PermissionNodeName =  "permission";
string roleFilter = "read";

JArray schemas = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (JObject schema in schemas)
{
    if (!schema.ContainsKey(RolesArrayName)) continue;
    foreach (JObject role in (JArray)schema[RolesArrayName])
    {
        if (!role.TryGetValue(RoleNodeName, out var roleNameToken)) continue;

        string roleName = (string)roleNameToken;
        if (!string.Equals(roleName, roleFilter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;

        if (!role.TryGetValue(PermissionNodeName, out var permission)) continue;
        if (!((JObject)permission).TryGetValue(roleFilter, out var granted)) continue;

        reduced.Add(new Schema
        {
            Name = (string)schema[SchemaNodeName],
            Role = roleName,
            Permission = new Permission
            {
                HasGranted = (bool)granted
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it's giving in result default value in ```permissions``` as read ```false```.Excepted is whatever is there value in Input jsonString.

Comment: @r08 Sorry but I can't follow you. I've asked it explicitly, you wrote that *it does not matter what value is there*. Now you are saying that it should be the same as in the input json. The expected output does not reflect that. So what do you really want?

Comment: yes it's doesn't matter whatever permission key it will come outside...i said value perspective..no need to check what value is there inside permission object .if ```"role"``` key contains values as user input value that means matching then put outside that object in crossponding Schema ```{"SchemaName":.....,"role":....,"permissions":{.....}}```

Comment: @r08 I've updated my post. Please check it that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Might be other possible way is there but here is the code how i achieve...

#### Parsing logic

```
string roleName="read";
var matchedSchemasObjectForRole =schemaArray.Where(schemaObject => schemaObject["roles"] != null && JArray.Parse(schemaObject["roles"].ToString()).Count > 0
   && JArray.Parse(schemaObject["roles"].ToString()).Any(x => x != null && x["role"]!=null && x["role"].ToString() == roleName.ToString())).Select(schemaObject => new ApplicationRolesCommon()
   {                               
       RoleName = roleName
       permissions = JArray.Parse(schemaObject["roles"].ToString()).Where(s => s["role"].ToString() == roleName.ToString() && s["permissions"]!=null).Select(s => new AppRoleFormSchemaPermissions
       {
           create = s["permissions"]["create"] !=null ? s["permissions"]["create"].ToObject<bool>() : false,
           read = s["permissions"]["read"] != null ? s["permissions"]["read"].ToObject<bool>() : false,
           update = s["permissions"]["update"] != null ? s["permissions"]["update"].ToObject<bool>() : false,
           delete = s["permissions"]["delete"] != null ? s["permissions"]["delete"].ToObject<bool>() : false
       }).First(),
       SchemaName = schemaObject["SchemaName"].ToString()

   }).ToList();
```

#### Domain model

```
public class ApplicationRolesCommon
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public AppRoleFormSchemaPermissions permissions { get; set; }
}

public class AppRoleFormSchemaPermissions
{
    public bool create { get; set; }
    public bool read { get; set; }
    public bool update { get; set; }
    public bool delete { get; set; }
}
```